# ReportViewer - Remote Mode Question

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008

We're considering using the VS 2010 Microsoft Report Viewer in Remote mode. My question has to do with is where data retrieval takes place. Let me give an example. Say we have a report with two parameters. These parameters are then passed as stored procedure parameters when data is retrieved. So, my question is, when is the stored procedure called? Is it called from the SSRS 2008 server and then the data and report sent to the report viewer client or, is the stored procedure called from the report viewer client? Secondly, let's say the report is being displayed in the report viewer client, and the user changes the parameter values and refreshes the report. Is the stored proc called from the client or is the stored proc somehow called from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In remote mode, all the report processing is carried out by the remote SSRS server - in your example, the stored procedure would be executed on the server and the report/data returned to the client.

If the parameters are changed and the report re-run in this scenario, a new report execution request is submitted from the client to the server, processed at the server and report/data returned to the client in the same way.

Comment: @Ed - Thank you! I can't tell you how difficult it's been to find a straight answer to this question. If I could vote you up 10 times, I would.

Comment: @Randy Minder - I know what you mean - all the VS documentation assumes that you understand how SSRS works - which is hard if you haven't worked with SSRS stand-alone.

Comment: @Ed - I'm going to ask another question related to this. Perhaps you could help me with that one as well.